# WPF: Listbox not Select and Highlight the selected Item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, listbox

Why is my Listbox not highlighting the item at the selectedIndex position?
At the Onloaded Event a method is executed to fill the itemsource and set the selectedIndex.
If i check the object at Code (see Attachment) the listbox looks good. But in the Ui the listboxitem is not highlighted.

Heres my Viewmodel:

```
    namespace listboxtest
{
    public class viewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<int> liste;
        public List<int> Liste
        {
            get { return liste; }
            set { liste = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        private int selecteditem;
        public int SelectedItem
        {
            get { return selecteditem; }
            set { selecteditem = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public viewmodel()
        {
            liste = new List<int>();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        public void fillList()
        {
            liste.Add(1);
            liste.Add(2);
            liste.Add(3);
            liste.Add(4);
            OnPropertyChanged("Liste");
            SelectedItem = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my view:

```
Here is my View:

       <Window.DataContext>
        <local:viewmodel ></local:viewmodel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Liste }" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedItem}" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded" >
                        <i:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="fillList" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: listbox object after setting selectedindex and fill itemsource]

Comment: I believe you need an `ObservableCollection` in stead of `List` - although: it might not fix the highlighting issue

Comment: Or you move `liste = new List<int>();` to the fillList method.

Comment: Thx very much. Both solutions are working. But the highlight looks different from the one when i click on a item with my mouse. Is this the normal behavior? And maybe a small explanation why this works.

Comment: You are probably confusing the selected item with the one that has keyboard focus.

Comment: Thanks very much. But whats different to my solution where i instantiate the list in the constructor?

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("Liste")` only has an effect when you assign a new value to the Liste property. Only adding items is something different. You would need to notfiy about that by using ObservableCollection.